# Este código en java para recorrer una matriz no esta bien

Tags: java

Solo imprime lo que va recorriendo, y en la recursividad de ida esta correcta y en la vuelta es donde tengo problemas

```
public class RecorrerUnaMatriz {
  public void recorrerUnaMatriz(int mat[][]){
    recorrerUnaMatriz(0,0,mat);
  }

  public void recorrerUnaMatriz(int i,int j, int mat[][]){
    if(i!=mat.length){
      if(j!=mat[i].length){
        System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        recorrerUnaMatriz(i,j+1,mat);
      }
      System.out.println();
      recorrerUnaMatriz(i+1,0,mat);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta y resulta apropiada una clausula `else` para cuando `j` haya llegado al ancho del *array* de lo contrario se estarán acumulando llamadas recursivas de mas que producen tantos saltos de lineas.

```
public void recorrerUnaMatriz(int i,int j, int mat[][]){
  if(i!=mat.length){
    if(j!=mat[i].length){
      System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
      recorrerUnaMatriz(i,j+1,mat);
    } else {
      System.out.println();
      recorrerUnaMatriz(i+1,0,mat);
    }
  }
}
```

De este modo se cambia la salida que antes pudiera ser:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9


7  8  9


7  8  9


4  5  6
7  8  9 

...
```

por:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Te recomiendo tomar el código con *debugger* y linea a linea ir mirando como es el flujo de ejecución con y sin el `else`.